# Get remaining time with an array for opening hours

Tags: javascript, time, countdown, hour

I'm trying to create a countdown to get the remaining time before my shop will close

```js
// My array for the opening hours :
var openTime = [
  { open : 9, close : 17},
  { open: 9, close : 18 },
  { open: 9, close : 18 },
  { open: 9, close : 18 },
  { open: 9, close : 18 }, 
  { open: 9, close : 18 },
  { open: 10, close : 16.5 }
]

var current = new Date();
var day = current.getDay();
var currentTime = current.getHours() + (current.getMinutes() / 60);
var remainTime = 0;

if (openTime[day].open >= 0 && openTime[day].open < currentTime && openTime[day].close >
  currentTime) {
  remainTime = (openTime[day].close - currentTime).toFixed(2)
}

console.log("the shop will close in %s hours", remainTime);
```

**But I have a problem with this line :**

```
var currentTime = current.getHours() + (current.getMinutes()/60);
```

Because when I execute the code, for exemple, actually it's 17h22, the code give me on my debugger that current time equal to 17.36 ?

There is something wrong with the line, because it's give me the wrong remaining time...

Comment: So the problem is that you haven't checked what the result of `22 / 60` (`current.getMinutes() / 60`) is?

Comment: Not really, the real problem it's that my code don't give the correct remaining time

Comment: Your code works. `22 / 60 ~ 0.36` exactly as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

0.36 of an hour (a decimal magnitude) equals 21.6 (≈22) minutes.

It's simple to convert decimal to minutes: `60*decimal`. Or `(60*decimal).toFixed(0)` or `(60*decimal).round()` if you want a round number.

Also, remember that JS uses the device's time. Today most devices sync their time, but if you don't want to rely on it, you should bring the time from your server (ie. storing it in a JS variable at preprocessing time, like `var time=<?=time()?>;`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want current time as string you have to:

```
var currentTime = current.getHours() + ":" + (current.getMinutes() / 60);
```

but thats not what you want I guess. You get of coures 17.36 because 17:22 converted to decimal base 10 instead of 60 minutes gives this value (22 min /60 =0.363636 rounded two digits 0.36). If you want to have the timer working you convert either back the decimal part by *60 to easy find it. Use:

```
 var decimalPart = remainTime % 1;
 var remainTimeHours =  remainTime - decimalPart;
var remainTimeMin  = decimalPart * 60;
```

Of course you can simplify it - just to show the logic
-in your closing time you use already 16.5 means 16:30 or should it be 16:50 -> then 16.83
or preferred seperate logic for hours and minutes not converted to decimal using even seconds if needed.